# How to define Object of Objects type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an object to store cached data which should look like this:

```
private data = {
   'some_thing': new DataModel(),
   'another_name': new DataModel()
}
```

I'm trying to assign an empty object to it in the constructor:

```
this.data = {}; // produces build error
```

Basically, i need to define the type of "data" field to say that it's going to have keys with random names and values of type DataModel. I've tried to do this:

```
private data: Object<DataModel>
```

But this is invalid. How would i specify a correct type?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

It should be:

```
private data: { [name: string]: DataModel };
```

And then this should work:

```
this.data = {};
```

Comment: Wish I give give this a million up votes! Thanks mate!